# Best way to Unit test non-existing Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, unit-testing

We have a build server which does not have a database running on its machine.
Now we want to make unit tests which also cover SQL-related tasks, for example writing mock-data and reading them again to verify the output (it gets manipulated by C# code in the process).

So the common approach would be to provide a connection-string to the remote server which actually runs a database. 
This works, but it is unwanted because the database-server could be inaccessible when the build is triggered, and therefore the automatic tests would **fail**.

What is the best way to create a "pseudo-database" while running Unit tests?
Is this even possible without an actual database? Does it even make sense?

Comment: What will be the point of exercising your unit tests against a Mock database? What will a passing (or failing) unit test tell you about the actual database?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ, having the mock database call via Mocking framework is the exact purpose of the mocking frameworks, unit test just means 1 unit no integration call

Answer (score 3):

Use mocking framework like `Moq`, check [here](http://www.developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/). That is the exact purpose of the Mocking frameworks that only a given component can be unit tested and any integration like database can be mocked to return the valid pre-defined result at the run-time and thus determine the working of given code / unit

Answer (score 1):

The commonly accepted answer to "how do I unit test something with external dependencies" is to use a mocking layer.

However, that very quickly becomes unwieldy - you end up writing and maintaining a lot of code just to mimic your database, and it's not clear this code will pay for itself. For instance, if your SQL statements has a typo, your unit tests won't catch that.

Instead, it is much better to factor the code which manipulates the data out into a layer which can be unit-tested without database access.